# Convert varchar MMDDYYYY to MM/DD/YYYY datetime and select the most recent date only

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, varchar

Okay, so I have kind of a weird issue... the dates in the table have been entered in as string values `MMDDYYYY` and I'm trying to have the displayed as `MM/DD/YYYY` in a report and only select the most recent date pertaining to an ID, because some ID's may have multiple dates.

Example of my table:

```
  ID  |  MyDate  |
------+----------+
  1   | 01302014 |
  1   | 04222014 |
  2   | 01302014 |
```

What I want to see when I select and insert into a temp table is this:

```
  ID  |   MyDate  |
------+-----------+
  1   | 4/22/2014 |
  2   | 1/30/2014 |
```

I know that storing dates as string values is a poor practice especially when storing them as `MMDDYYYY`, but does anyone have a solution to this nightmare?

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that some fields might be NULL. Not sure if that makes a difference or not, but I think it does if I try to flip the dates using Right, Left, Convert.

Comment: Do you control the database? If so, it would be a *very* good idea to change the schema so that the `MyDate` column is a `Date` column instead of `varchar`. You've already said that you know that storing the dates as string values is a poor practice - so can you fix it? Once you've done that, everything else becomes much easier. Tackle the source of the problem rather than its most immediate symptom.

Comment: The biggest single recommendation I can give you is to never ever ever ever store dates as strings.  Beyond that.  Temporarily CAST the MyDate to a date data type and then use the CONVERT to put it in the format you want.

Comment: I wish I had that authority. I mentioned it to others that I could go ahead and change all of the dates to be proper date format, but they want to keep it as varchar for the way that dates are being entered in through indexing softwares.

Comment: If you can't say it to them, point them to this comment of mine here now: They're idiots. Pure idiots.

Comment: I don't think it deserves a downvote IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is for almost a year ago, nut probably someone can find it useful.

You need to `CONVERT` your string to `DATE` format and use a `ROW_NUMBER` function to window your result set.

**Create table**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Id INT, myDate VARCHAR(8))
```

**Sample data**

```
INSERT @tbl
SELECT 1  ,  '01302014' UNION ALL
SELECT 1  ,  '04222014' UNION ALL
SELECT 2  ,  '01302014'
```

**Query**

```
;WITH C AS(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, (SUBSTRING(myDate, 5, 4) + '.' + SUBSTRING(myDate, 1, 2) + '.' + SUBSTRING(myDate, 3, 2)), 101) DESC) AS Rn
            ,Id
            ,CAST(CONVERT(DATETIME, (SUBSTRING(myDate, 5, 4) + '.' + SUBSTRING(myDate, 1, 2) + '.' + SUBSTRING(myDate, 3, 2)), 101) AS DATE) AS myDate
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT Id, myDate
FROM C
WHERE Rn = 1
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/46c23/2)

Comment: Conversion expression can be simplified: `CONVERT(DATE, RIGHT(myDate, 4) + LEFT(myDate, 4), 112)`

Answer (score 1):

Using a CONVERT like the following code snippet will work on any SQL Server regardless of language and/or locale configuration.

```
DECLARE @OldDate varchar(8); 
SELECT @OldDate = '04252012';

SELECT CONVERT(datetime, substring(@OldDate,5,4) + '-' + substring(@OldDate,1,2) + '-' + substring(@OldDate,3,2) + 'T00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select id,convert(varchar(11),cast(dateValue as Date),101)
From
(
Select id,MAX(cast(MyDate As Date)) as dateValue
From tableName
Group By id
) t
```

Comment: The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

Comment: That means some value stored in table cannot be converted to datetime. This is why date values should not be stored as strings as there is no guarantee that value entered corresponds to a valid date type value .Use isdate() function to check which are those values

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
convert(date,SUBSTRING (MyDate,1,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING (MyDate,3,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING (MyDate,5,4),101)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select CONVERT(datetime,RIGHT('01302014',4) +
                       LEFT('01302014',2) +
                       SUBSTRING('01302014',3,2))

'2014-01-30 00:00:00.000'

;with Cte as (Select Id,CONVERT(datetime,RIGHT(MyDate,4)+LEFT(MyDate,2)+SUBSTRING(MyDate,3,2)) as sDate, C=ROW_NUMBER()
over(PARTITION By Id Order by MyDate desc)
From #Temp)

select * 
from Cte
where C=1
```

Answer (score 0):

First do a conversion to a `datetime` datatype, then convert it to a format you wish to:

```
select id, convert(varchar, max(convert(datetime,right(mydate, 4)+left(mydate,4))), 101)
from #t
group by id
```

Although I can't understand why would it not suffice to just convert it do `datetime` and leave the formatting where it belongs, to the client.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is mySQL [str_to_date()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function.

```
STR_TO_DATE(`MyDate`, '%m%d%Y')
```

This will convert it to a DATETIME which you then format as required

```
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`MyDate`, '%m%d%Y'), '%c/%e/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete Query:

```
Select ID, Case When IsDate(RIGHT(MyDate,4)+LEFT(MyDate,2)+SUBSTRING(MyDate,3,2)) = 1 
THEN Convert(varchar(10), Convert(datetime, RIGHT(MyDate,4)+LEFT(MyDate,2)+SUBSTRING(MyDate,3,2)), 101) 
        ELSE Null END AS MyDate FROM YourTable a where Case When IsDate(RIGHT(MyDate,4)+LEFT(MyDate,2)+SUBSTRING(MyDate,3,2)) = 1 
        THEN Convert(varchar(10), Convert(datetime,  RIGHT(MyDate,4)+LEFT(MyDate,2)+SUBSTRING(MyDate,3,2)), 101) 
        ELSE Null END = (Select Max(Case When IsDate(RIGHT(MyDate,4)+LEFT(MyDate,2)+SUBSTRING(MyDate,3,2)) = 1 
        THEN Convert(varchar(10), Convert(datetime, RIGHT(MyDate,4)+LEFT(MyDate,2)+SUBSTRING(MyDate,3,2)), 101) 
        ELSE Null END)
        FROM YourTable b
        Where a.ID = b.ID
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a modified version from Dimitris Kalaitzis' answer.

First, you will need to convert your MyDate into String.  The data for example (01302014) is not treated as a string and the leading zero will be removed when you convert it.  Therefore, use CAST to make MyDate as a String and add a leading 0 to it.  Then you find the right 8 characters so to get rid of the leading zero for months from Oct to Dec.

Here is the code that should work for you:

```
CONVERT(Date, SUBSTRING(RIGHT('0' + CAST(MyDate AS VARCHAR(10)), 8), 1, 2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(RIGHT('0' + CAST(MyDate AS VARCHAR(10)), 8), 3, 2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(RIGHT('0' + CAST(MyDate AS VARCHAR(10)), 8), 5, 4), 101)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to add the slashes to be able to convert it to a date, use STUFF
Then convert it to a DATE and select the MAX group by ID

Query:

```
SELECT ID, FORMAT(MAX(CONVERT(DATE,STUFF(STUFF(MyDate,3,0,'/'),6,0,'/'))),'MM/dd/yyyy') AS MyDate FROM TableName
GROUP BY ID
```