# Convert MMddyyyy varchar into MM/dd/yy date

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, casting

I have a table of data that has a lot of junk in the date field.  I need to first get only the records that have dates in it, so I have created a temp table to filter it down.  Then I am converting it to a date from the MMddyyyy varchar format.  This much I can get:

```
    select  f.filenumber as claimnumber, 
            f.filename as Name,
            f.charvalue as OtherDate,
            f.charvalue as TempDate
    into #TempClaims
    from Table f
    and isnumeric(f.charvalue) = 1
    and len(f.charvalue) = 8
    and f.charvalue not like '%.%'

Update #TempClaims
    set TempDate = DATEFROMPARTS(right(TempDate,4), left(tempdate, 2), substring(TempDate, 3, 2)) 

    Select claimnumber, Name, OtherDate,  TempDate as DateOfLoss 
    From #TempClaims
    order by DateOfLoss
```

I need it in a proper date format so I can sort by it. My company was just mimicking what the date format looks like but kept it as a string, so we couldn't sort on it.

The OtherDate field is just temporary so I can compare the results of the new date field to make sure it is correct.  This code gives me yyyy-mm-dd, while that is a superior date format I am in the United States and my users would not understand it.

Whenever I add Format(TempDate, 'MM/dd/yy') as DateOfLoss it crashes with this error:

> Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dbo.SearchForClaim, Line 57 [Batch Start Line 2]
> Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 1 of format function.

So it isn't a date yet? I have tried multiple solutions:

[Convert string MMDDYYYY to a Date](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/convert-string-mmddyyyy-to-a-date)

[Convert varchar MMDDYYYY to MM/DD/YYYY datetime and select the most recent date only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23297326/convert-varchar-mmddyyyy-to-mm-dd-yyyy-datetime-and-select-the-most-recent-date)

Comment: `f.charvalue as TempDate` <= i doubt that `charvalue` is a Date type based on the name. That is the problem when you try to update that column because the schema does not match. You need a `Date` column type to fill. You could add this to your select statement `cast(null as Date) as ActualDate` and then change the `update` statement to `set ActualDate = DATEFROMPARTS....`

Comment: Do keep in mind that `Date`, `DateTime`, and `DateTime2` types do not have a format and are not stored as a formatted string. You only perceive a format because you are human so the default display shows you the value formatted in ISO8601 notation. The displayed format is not a concern of the persistence layer, it is a concern for the presentation layer where the value is rendered for a human to see it. If you are worried about how you export the value directly from SQL there are options to format it as you see fit but most of the time the application layer should deal with this for you.

Comment: In your temporary table `tempdate` is a varchar not a date ...

Comment: Like I answered in the other question, fix your design. Stop using a string based data type for a date, it's the *wrong* data type.

Comment: @ThomA I can't.  That is pulling data from a 3rd party application we use.  It is how they store the data. I would not store it that way if I had control over the data.

Comment: @derpirscher I understand but I am trying many different methods to convert it to a date.

Comment: Perhaps you should be contacting the 3rd party and getting them to fix their foolish, and fatally flawed, design then, @djblois .

Comment: @ThomA yeah that will work.  Instead of trying to help my problem?

Comment: I've already closed this as a duplicate to help you, @djblois . If none of those answers solve the problem, you need to [edit] your question to explain why. Ideally provide sample data and expected results, and possibly demonstrate your attemp(s) to implement the solutions proposed.

Comment: @ThomA if those solutions didn't help me - which they didn't - how is that helping me?  I already did that.  I gave the solutions I tried and it isn't working at the bottom of the original post.

Comment: Yes, and I've duplicated this of a different post that was literally posted a couple of days ago for the same problem; those solutions will work. If none of them are then I would suggest your implementation is wrong; unfortunately with no [mre] or sample data I cannot tell you why and this I'm not happy to reopen the question. It still looks like a duplicate to me.

Comment: The **BEST** thing  you could do (by far!) is update the application so this data is cleaned and converted to a date value at INSERT/UPDATE time, with an actual date column. It will reduce storage, memory and CPU use, give you easier access to date functions, and work better with indexes. It will also increase developer productivity and help you write better code in the first place (since you no longer need to do things like copy to a temp table first).

Comment: Update #TempClaims
    set TempDate = DATEFROMPARTS(right(TempDate,4), left(tempdate, 2), substring(TempDate, 3, 2)) 
this doesn't actually change the *data type* to date. It just set it to a *date* that gets converted to varchar, which is the real data type. What you need to do is create a new date column that you update by the above value

Comment: As a side note, I do recommend against 2 digits for the year. We don't need a Y2.1k bug too. Be specific and define the year properly.

Comment: Something like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/yN64iXyD